# Replace string but only for particular pattern in c#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have 2 strings, one is main string and other is pattern string to be replaced. I want to replace the some part of main string with pattern string only if particular pattern is matched in main string.

Example:

```
string mainstring = "[def].[ijk] = [abc].[def].[ijk]";
string pattern =    "[lmn].[def].[ijk]";
```

i want final string as

> [lmn].[def].[ijk] = [abc].[def].[ijk]

i.e. if only 2 part is there in string than only replace not for 3 parts

i am using:

```
mainstring = mainstring.Replace("[def].[ijk]",pattern);
```

but it replaces as,

```
[lmn].[def].[ijk] = [abc].[lmn].[def].[ijk]
                          ^-------+-------^
                                  |
                                  +-- don't replace here
```

but I want as

> [lmn].[def].[ijk] = [abc].[def].[ijk]

EDIT: Additional rule for the replacement:

You can touch left hand side or right hand side but the pattern should be alone without anything at before or after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to follow this rule:

> i.e. if only 2 part is there in string than only replace not for 3 parts

(interpreting it as replace only if the matching pattern is not inbetween other parts, or: neither preceded nor follwed by a `.`)

This regular expression should satisfy this rule above:

```
string mainstring = "[def].[ijk] = [abc].[def].[ijk]";
// will replace only right side
//string mainstring = "[abc].[def].[ijk] = [def].[ijk]"; 

string replacement = "[lmn].[def].[ijk]";

string pattern = @"(?<!\.)\[def\].\[ijk\](?!\.)";

string output = Regex.Replace(mainstring, pattern, replacement);
```

**EDIT:**

if you need to transform you basic pattern into a regex format replace both parentheses:

```
string searchPattern  = "[def].[ijk]";

searchPattern = searchPattern.Replace("[", @"\[").Replace("]", @"\]");
```

and place the result in between the look ahead and look behind pattern:

```
string pattern = @"(?<!\.)" + searchPattern + @"(?!\.)";
```

**Explanation:**

`(?<!\.)`: the pattern is called negative lookahead. It will match only if the preceding character is not a `.` (dot)

`(?!\.)`: the pattern is called negative lookbehind. It will match only if the following character is not a `.` (dot)

the replacement of `[ ]` to `\[ \]` is necessary because regex treats the parentheses as an interval or group and matches every character between the parentheses. Like `[0-9]` will match any digit between `0` and `9`. But if you use an escape sequence `@"\[0-9\]"` it will take the parentheses as a character and match the pattern `"[0-9]"`. I hope it became a little clearer

Comment: i can split the problem is the split character is not fix. i.e. it can have `=`,`!=`, `<`,`>`,`<>` and other operators. so using particular character string wont help also it is not fixed which part should be replaced, i.e. in example you r replacing on [0]th index, but my pattern can be on any index

Comment: @Arc then you really should specify exactly how the rules are for replacement. If there is no clear rule, or at least a couple of contraints this will be very difficult to solve.

Comment: Following are some rules,to be followed : 1. The split characters are not fixed, any character can be there (like `=`,`!=`,`<`,`>`,`<>`) 2. the patterns position is not fixed, it can be either left or right side of split character. And split characters are only above specified, it can be `+,-,*,/,&,(,),And, Or, Not,=,<>,<,<=,>=,>`. also all the text functions, date function, conversion function, text function, summary functions, logical operators

Comment: @Arc which rule determines that only the left handside in your example should be replaced but not the right handside?

Comment: That is what i am saying, it can be on any side, either left or right side :(

Comment: In your example you say that the right hand side is to be left untouched although the pattern is present. so replace only if it the pattern is standing alone without anything before and behind it?=! is this right?

Comment: You can touch left hand side or right hand side but the pattern should be alone without anything at before or after. I hope this will help :(

Comment: @Arc here we go, I found a regex that matches only if the pattern is standing alone withou anything preceding of floowing it. Have a look

Comment: But how can i add my custom strings into it? i have pattern in variable, how can i add it? let say my pattern is in `searchPattern` variable, how can i append in regex expression?

Comment: @Arc I edited my post. You need to transform into the regex format and place it inbetween the looka around patterns. Have a look

Comment: @ Mong Zhu,I am working with your code now, can you please explain the code how it works? According to @AmoT, we have to use `\[` instead of `[`, what is the reason for that? also u used `(?<!\.)`, what it stands for?

Comment: @Arc I added an explanation to my post, you can have a look at [/regex-lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). Is my explanation understandable? I also added an explanation for the replacement of the parentheses

Comment: @ Mong Zhu, it is working. thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Not good but work;

```
       string mainstring = "[def].[ijk] = [abc].[def].[ijk]";
       string pattern = "[lmn].[def].[ijk]";
        string search ="[def].[ijk]";
        string mainstring3 = "";
       string[] mainstring2 = mainstring.Split(' ');
       for (int i = 0; i < mainstring2.Length; i++)
       {
           if (mainstring2[i] == search)
           {
               mainstring2[i] = pattern;
           }
           if (i < mainstring2.Length - 1)
           {
               mainstring3 += mainstring2[i] + " ";
           }
           else
           {
               mainstring3 += mainstring2[i];
           }
       }
       mainstring = mainstring3;
    }
```

Comment: string to replace will not only `[def].[lkj]`, so what i did is `var rege = @"\b"+stringtosearch+"\b";`, this results in `\b[def].[ijk]`, and this pattern is not present in original string

Comment: `\b[def].[ijk]\b`, this is what i am getting

Comment: if you want to capture `[` as a character you need to use `@"\[...` other wise regex will interpret it as any character between the parentheses

Comment: But how can i solve my issue? brackets are there in string. What i want to do is just replace only if `[def].[ijk]` and not if `[abc].[def].[ijk]` in entire string. Any suggestions?

Comment: this will not match if the expression is standing alone on the right hand side: `"[abc].[def].[ijk] = [def].[ijk]"`

Comment: @MongZhu You are right. I will try for new solution

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
 string mainstring = "[def].[ijk] = [abc].[def].[ijk]";

            string leftFillWith = "[lmn].[def].[ijk]";

            string pattern = @"((\[lmn\]).)?((\[def\]).)?(\[ijk\])? =";

          var expected=  Regex.Replace(mainstring, pattern,match=> leftFillWith+" =" );
```

if only two parts are accepted:

```
  string mainstring = "[def].[ijk] = [abc].[def].[ijk]";

            string leftFillWith = "[lmn].[def].[ijk]";

           // string pattern = @"((\[lmn\]).)?((\[def\]).)?(\[ijk\])? ="; //if any number of parts is accepted on left


          string  pattern = @"(\[def\]\.\[ijk\])(\s)+="; //if only two parts are accepted

            string expected = Regex.IsMatch(mainstring,pattern)? Regex.Replace(mainstring, pattern, match => leftFillWith + " ="):mainstring;
```

Comment: can you add little explanation what is happening? is i am little confused in last two lines of your snippet

Comment: `pattern` searches on left side of `mainstring` for the bracketed units. You can see there are questionmarks in the pattern, so it means that they are optional: not requiered as there may be not constant amount of unit on left side. So this pattern finds the left-sided combination and replaces it with `leftFillWith` by adding "=" sign at the end with " "(space) off course.

Comment: @Arc your pattern was `[lmn]`. It searches for "l", "m", "n", but not for "lmn". These brackets are for classes ranges, but not for units. I guess you confused just because there lots of parentheses. But it helps as "combines".

Comment: But how can i solve my issue? brackets are there in string. What i want to do is just replace only if `[def].[ijk]` and not if `[abc].[def].[ijk]` in entire string

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @Arc no problem. See my edited posrt. There is `(\s)+` if more than one " " occurs in string ;)

Comment: @arc what do you mean by "But how can i solve my issue? brackets are there in string". What's a problem with brackets? If you want to find bracket use `\[`, but not `[`. I used this in my examples. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: I used your code as it is, it works fine but i have the search pattern in variable, what to do in that case? how can i write the `string pattern = @"(\[def\]\.\[ijk\])(\s)+=";` using my variable say variable name is `searchString`? also you have done using only `=`, in my case operator is not fixed :(

Comment: if i remove `+=` than it will work, also what if my main string is `"[def].[ijk] * [def].[ijk]";`? cant i have single regex expression to cover all case?